# Show Post submit popup message in ASP.Net Core Razor page without controller

Tags: asp.net-core, razor, popup, alert

I have an ASP.Net Core Razor web application without controllers.
I have a form in my cshtml page and on Post/Submit I am calling an external API, which returns a success message or an error message. I want to show this message in my page as a popup.
I tried multiple things but failed. Here is my code.

In my "Index.cshtml"

```
<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 footer-newsletter">
     <h4>Our Newsletter</h4>
     <p>Subscribe to our news letter</p>
     <form action="" method="post">
           <input type="email" asp-for="SubscriptionEmail" placeholder="Email Address"/>
           <input type="submit" value="Subscribe" asp-page-handler="NewsSubscription" />
     </form>
</div>
```

In my Index.cshtml.cs

```
[BindProperty]
public string SubscriptionEmail { get; set; }

public string ActionResultMessageText { get; set; }
public string ActionResultErrorMessageText { get; set; }
```

```
public async void OnPostNewsSubscription()
{
    try
    {
        this.ActionResultMessageText = string.Empty;
        this.ActionResultErrorMessageText = string.Empty;
        using (HttpClient _httpClient = _httpClientFactory.CreateClient("PortalBasicHttpClient"))
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(SubscriptionEmail))
            {
                HttpRequestMessage _Request = new(HttpMethod.Post, _httpClient.BaseAddress + "Api/SaveSubscriptionEmail/" + SubscriptionEmail);
                HttpResponseMessage _Response = await _httpClient.SendAsync(_Request);
                if (_Response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    this.ActionResultMessageText = _Response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result.ToString();
                }
                else
                {
                    this.ActionResultMessageText = _Response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result.ToString();
                }           
            }
       }
   }
   catch (Exception ex)
   {
       _logger.LogError(ex, ex.Message);
       this.ActionResultMessageText = string.Empty;
       this.ActionResultErrorMessageText = ex.Message;
                
    }
            
}
```

My code behind is working fine, but not sure how to grace fully show this in the razor page using bootstrap.
looking forward for some guidance.

I tried using modal popup, but the text was not updated in the label I used in the modal popup and the pop-up disappeared with in few seconds, even though there was a "ok" button.

I also tried to use the java script method as mentioned in the following link https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/ASPNet-Core-Razor-Pages-Display-JavaScript-Alert-Message-Box.aspx

I will be great help if someone can help with a sample code.

Comment: Hi @Mrinmoy Das, it works fine in my project. Could you pls share what is your front js code like?  Also, please debug your backend code to be sure the two properties actually contain the value you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please debug your code and be sure **the two properties actually contain the value you want**.

The following working demo I just hard coded the two properties value for easy testing in the backend:

Index.cshtml

```
@page
@model IndexModel
<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 footer-newsletter">
    <h4>Our Newsletter</h4>
    <p>Subscribe to our news letter</p>
    <form action="" method="post">
        <input type="email" asp-for="SubscriptionEmail" placeholder="Email Address" />
        <input type="submit" value="Subscribe" asp-page-handler="NewsSubscription" />
    </form>
</div>
@if (Model.ActionResultMessageText == string.Empty)
{
    <script type="text/javascript">
        window.onload = function () {
            alert("@Model.ActionResultErrorMessageText");
        };
    </script>
}
```

Index.cshtml.cs

```
public class IndexModel : PageModel
{
    private readonly ILogger<IndexModel> _logger;

    public IndexModel(ILogger<IndexModel> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }
    [BindProperty]
    public string SubscriptionEmail { get; set; }

    public string ActionResultMessageText { get; set; }
    public string ActionResultErrorMessageText { get; set; }
    public void OnGet()
    {
        
    }
    public async void OnPostNewsSubscription()
    {
        this.ActionResultMessageText = string.Empty;
        this.ActionResultErrorMessageText = "error";

    }
}
```

Result:

[image]

---

If you want to use **Bootstrap modal popup**, change your page like below:

```
@page
@model IndexModel
<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 footer-newsletter">
    <h4>Our Newsletter</h4>
    <p>Subscribe to our news letter</p>
    <form action="" method="post">
        <input type="email" asp-for="SubscriptionEmail" placeholder="Email Address" />
        <input type="submit" value="Subscribe" asp-page-handler="NewsSubscription" />
    </form>
</div>

<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h1 class="modal-title fs-5" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h1>
        <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
            @Model.ActionResultErrorMessageText       
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
@if (Model.ActionResultMessageText == string.Empty)
{
    <script type="text/javascript">
        window.onload = function () {
            $("#exampleModal").modal("show")
        };
    </script>
}
```

Result:
[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot Rena, for taking time to answer with the code. I am new to .Net Core. Your response helped a lot. However, I am yet make it work. you are right, something is going wrong in my post method call. While debugging it updated the values, but the alert is shown before the property gets update. by hardcoding the property value the hardcoded text is shown. Most probably something going wrong with the async call.